# How to distribute list of even/noteven elements to index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there any way to produce below output as I desire

I have pd.dataframe as below:

```
df1

   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
```

and i want to add column of list

```
lst1 = ['TEXT1','TEXT2']
lst2 = ['text1','text2','text3']
```

For lst1 case it is working on df1 because index value and passed value are dividable
I 
Input:

```
    lst1 = ['TEXT1' , 'TEXT2']
    df1['text'] = np.repeat(lst1, len(df2) // len(lst1))
```

Output on lst1:

```
1 TEXT1
2 TEXT1
3 TEXT1
4 TEXT1
5 TEXT2
6 TEXT2
7 TEXT2
8 TEXT2
```

My desired output for lst2:

```
    1 text1
    2 text1
    3 text1
    4 text2
    5 text2
    6 text2
    7 text3
    8 text3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `index` and then use `.ngroup()` as index to your list:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'data': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
lst2 = ['text1','text2','text3']

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['txt'] = df.groupby(df.index // len(lst2)).ngroup().map(lst2.__getitem__)    # or .apply(lambda x: lst2[x])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   data    txt
0     1  text1
1     2  text1
2     3  text1
3     4  text2
4     5  text2
5     6  text2
6     7  text3
7     8  text3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to group here, you can just repeat and then cut off whatever you don't need:

```
df1['text'] = np.repeat(lst2, np.ceil(len(df1) / len(lst2)))[:len(df1)]
df1
   data   text
0     1  text1
1     2  text1
2     3  text1
3     4  text2
4     5  text2
5     6  text2
6     7  text3
7     8  text3
```